# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.urls'---terminal has stuck and i can't do anything

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

hope you are well ,
I am new , please i need yur help .
My terminal has stuck after this msg has show " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.urls'
and i cant continue with my runserver.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FHyW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking like you have put **mysite** folder inside **myapp** folder. Just move your **mysite** folder one level up.

Structure should be

```
|- mysite

|-- mysite
|--- urls.py
|--- settings.py

|-- myapp
|--- urls.py
|--- views.py
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: you miss spelled urls.py]

refactor myapp/Urls.py to myapp/urls.py
the problem is the U the first letter make it lower case